# how to draw line graph using listbox values

Tags: vb.net, charts, listbox, richtextbox

I was looking for the answer to my question but all codes I tried didn't work for me so I decided to ask for help.
I am newbie with making charts in VB.net and my boss wants results (by yesterday) so I don't have time to dig deeper into how to make charts.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim a As Double
Dim b As String
b = RichTextBox1.Text
a = Convert.ToDouble(b)
'Chart1.DataBindTable(b)
' Chart1.(RichTextBox1.Text)
'Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindY(RichTextBox1.Text)
'Convert.ToInt32(b, 0)
Chart1.DataSource = RichTextBox1.Text
'Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindY(RichTextBox1.Text)
'Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(b)

'Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = b
Me.Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(a)
'MsgBox(RichTextBox1.Text)
MsgBox(a)
'Me.Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.InsertY(b)

Me.Refresh()

End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load

 End Sub
```

I would like to draw a line graph.
I have a listbox with 10 numbers and a button. I would like to make a line chart from those numbers.
I also tried to use richtextbox instead of the listbox but no luck.
I would like to get something like the attached picture.

Thank you so much for help.
[sample made in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP2dq.jpg)

Comment: Please share some details about the contents of the list box and how/what you've done so far. A 2-D graph has Point (x,y), what is the other value ?

Comment: RichTextBox?  Post code of what you tried.

Comment: "all codes I tried didn't work for me" Well, what code did you try and what didn't work? Here is a simple example of adding a single point. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Update---
Replace this part in the Points region of code provided below

```
   Dim x2 As Integer = 0 ' Keep a track of index
   For Each i As Integer In ListBox1.Items
        ' create a Point with index as x and the actual value of list item as y
         s.Points.AddXY(Convert.toDouble(x2), Convert.toDouble(i))
         x2 = x2+1
   Next
```

A chart should be something like this

```
 Chart1.Series.Clear() 'Empty your chart of any previous values

 Chart1.Titles.Add("My Line chart") 'Add a Title

 Dim s As New Series 'Create a new series
 s.Name = "My Line" 'Series name

 s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line 'Chart type

 'Most important part, the points to plot
 'Points START
  s.Points.AddXY(1, 2)
  s.Points.AddXY(3, 4)
  s.Points.AddXY(5, 9)
 'Points END

 'Add the series to the Chart1 control
 Chart1.Series.Add(s)
```

I'm not sure why you are using a RichTextBox1. If you are gathering user input (x,y) points then you will need to construct your points.
Use a `TextBox` control instead of `RichText`, it should suffice, with the given description.

Replace the Points bit in the above code with this

```
'Assume the user is entering value/numbers separated by ","
'Use the input as both x and y
'e.g 1,2,3,...
Dim textCont As String = TextBox.Text
Dim boxValues As String() = textCont.Split(New Char() {","})
For Each item In boxValues
 s.Points.AddXY(Convert.toDouble(item), Convert.toDouble(item))
 s.Points.AddXY(Convert.toDouble(item), Convert.toDouble(item))
 s.Points.AddXY(Convert.toDouble(item), Convert.toDouble(item))
Next
```

As far as the code you've provided, there is no `ListBox` control or reference to use in this example.

[AddXY(Double,Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467348(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, the reason for having richtextbox instead of listbox was that I changed all listboxes to richtextboxes to test if it will work like that. I already have numbers in the listbox which I am populating from another form. Technically the X axis will be the number of points and the Y will be the values (numbers from the listbox)

Comment: The code you sent works great, but I need to read those numbers from the Listbox1

Comment: Where does the `ListBox` get data from ? Can this `Form` access it ? Update the Question with the `Listbox` reference u have.It will help.

Comment: I modified the code a little bit. I have 2 forms The form1 I have is named Main. I have a Listbox2 on that form that gets the number from a 3rd party display unit. That unit populates the Listbox2 with numbers. Every number is in new line in that Listbox2. I have the second form called X_axis_chart which has a ListBox1. I am basically copying the values from the Main form listbox into the other listbox. Using those numbers I would like to make a line chart. Maybe the listbox on the second Form is not needed, I don't know. I will post the new code now. I got rid the button on the form2.

Comment: I have a menu on Main form that opens the second form.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks it is working. The reason I am not sure is because I can't test it out since they are using the 3rd party display which feeds the program with information. I populated the Listbox manually and it is working. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified form2

Public Class X_axis_chart

```
Private Sub X_axis_chart_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim a As Integer
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For a = 0 To Main.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Step 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Main.ListBox2.Items.Item(a).ToString)
    Next
    'Chart1.Series("X axis").Points.DataBindY(ListBox1.Text)
    Chart1.Series("X axis").Points.AddXY("Text", ListBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You should always put your code updates in the Question. Never in the Answers.